# Using Auto Size class hides the view

Tags: ios, iphone

Following is screenshot of my xib :

[image]

And this is what appears on simulator :

[image]

I don't know why some part of the view is hidden although I have used **wAny hAny**.

Comment: Do the views on the right side have constraints to the left side of the view?

Comment: I don't think there is any constraint on any of the view. Otherwise it would had been there on view list on left side of first screenshot.

Comment: Did you explicitly turn off auto layout? If not, then it's on, and the system will add constraints for you, but they probably won't be the ones you want.

Comment: Auto layout was already checked. How do I disable those constraints then if that you are suggesting ?

Comment: I don't know if you can use size classes without auto layout, so to prevent the system from adding constraints, you need to add your own.

Comment: Correct. I added constraints to the views and now they are appearing good.

Comment: You might want to add this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using auto layout, it's best, in almost every case, to add them yourself, rather than letting the system add them for you -- the system will do that if auto layout is on (Which it is by default) and you don't explicitly add constraints. If you add a view to the canvas, select it, and switch to the size inspector, you will see this message,

> The selected views have no constraints. At build time, explicit left,
>   top, width, and height constraints will be generated for the view.

If you are using wAny hAny, a view that's near the right edge of the view is going to get a constraint to the left side that will be very large, something like 500, so that will be off screen on any phone. You need to add your own constraint to the right side instead.